# Build Calendar with Day/Week and Month view for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I need to add a calendar (with day/ week / and month view) to my app, it tried [tapku](http://tapku.com/) but it only have the month view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [iPhone Day Calendar View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019214/iphone-day-calendar-view)
 or [How can I get the UI Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423218/how-can-i-get-the-ui-calendar)

Different options are,

1. [ios-calendar-views](http://www.e-string.com/content/ios-calendar-views)
2. [GCCalendar](https://github.com/guicocoa/calendar)
3. [muhku](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JTCalendar](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar) you have a month view and a week view, it's open source, works on iOS 7 and 8.